# How to print a grid with multiple columns in the terminal using for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a grid in Python that uses different symbols (+, -, |) using ONLY For loops and functions. It's supposed to be a 2 by 'n' grid, with 'n' being the argument of the function that the user will enter input for.
[This is what it should look like if n = 2]

```
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
```

Here's what I've gotten so far:

```
#function for 2byN grid
def print_2byN(n):
  def print_2byN_rows_columns(r): #r = rows
    for x in range(r):
      for y in range(n):
        print('+', '- '*4, end='')
        print('+')
        for num in range(4):
          print('|', '  '*4, end='')
          print('|')
    print('+', '- '*4, end='')
    print('+')
  print_2byN_rows_columns(2)

#Main
print_2byN(int(input("Enter an integer for 2byN: ")))
```

When I input "1" for n I get this (which is supposed to happen):

```
+ - - - - +
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
+ - - - - +
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
+ - - - - +
```

When I input "2" for n I get this (which isn't supposed to happen):

```
+ - - - - +
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
+ - - - - +
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
+ - - - - +
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
+ - - - - +
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
+ - - - - +
```

Comment: Why do you define an inner function? IMO that makes everything unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I agree, I initially had just one function which made it much easier, but my instructor wanted two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce columns, you must add a for loop using `n`, like this: `for _ in range(n)`.

I changed your code as little as possible to get the desired result:

```
#function for 2byN grid
def print_2byN(n):
    def print_2byN_rows_columns(r): #r = rows2
        for _ in range(r):
            for _ in range(n):
                print('+', '- '*4, end='')
            print('+')
            for _ in range(4):
                for _ in range(n):
                    print('|', '  '*4, end='')
                print('|')
        for _ in range(n):
            print('+', '- '*4, end='')
        print('+')
    print_2byN_rows_columns(2)

#Main1
print_2byN(int(input("Enter an integer for 2byN: ")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to craft the individual lines depending on the value of `n`, then reuse them in a simple loop:

I used 2 different parameters for the number of rows and columns here for clarity.

```
def grid(rows, cols):
    assert rows>0, 'rows must be >0'
    assert cols>0, 'cols must be >0'
    line = '+%s +' % ' +'.join([' -'*4]*cols)
    space = '|%s |' % ' |'.join(['  '*4]*cols)
    for _ in range(rows):
        print(line)
        for _ in range(4):
            print(space)
    print(line)
```

Example:

```
# grid(2, 2)
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
```

NB. if you don't want to use `join`, you can replace:

```
line = '+%s +' % ' +'.join([' -'*4]*cols)
```

by:

```
line = '+'
for _ in range(cols):
    line += (' -'*4) + ' +'
```

And similarly for `space`.

Comment: I believe there's only ever supposed to be 2 rows. The OP calls it a "2 by 'n' grid"

Comment: @001 I added a separate parameter for the columns, this doesn't change the overall logic ;)

Comment: I might have misunderstood. OP calls the inner function `print_2byN_rows_columns` so, I guess, 2 columns, by `n` rows. You probably had it right the first time.

Comment: @001 I made the function generic, if OP wants make a n * n function then just force `rows = cols` ;)

Comment: @JonSG yes I didn't pay enough attention initially, fixed now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```py
def print_2byN(n):
    for x in range(2):
        # Top border of the cell
        for y in range(n):
            print('+', '- ' * 4, end='')
        print('+')

        # Interior of the cell
        for num in range(4):
            for y in range(n):
                print('|', '  ' * 4, end='')
            print('|')

    # Bottom border of the last row
    for y in range(n):
        print('+', '- ' * 4, end='')
    print('+')
```

**Note**: I've removed the `print_2byN_rows_columns` because it isn't necessary, you can use `range(2)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked your code a bit - it seems to work. Got rid of function defined inside function, unused variables and added some parameters to play with.

```
def print_2byN_rows_columns(cols, rows=2, square_size=4):
    for _ in range(rows):
        for _ in range(cols):
            print('+', '- ' * square_size, end='')
        print('+')
        
        for _ in range(square_size):
            for _ in range(cols):
            
                print('|', '  ' * square_size, end='')
            print('|')

    for _ in range(cols):
        print('+', '- ' * square_size, end='')
    print('+')

#Main
cols = int(input("Enter an integer for 2byN: "))
print_2byN_rows_columns(cols, rows=2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
#function for 2byN grid
def print_2byN(n):
  def separator(n):
    print('+', end='')
    for x in range(n):
      print(' - - - - +', end='')
    print()

  def space(n):
    print('|', end='')
    for x in range(n):
      print('         |', end='')
    print()

  separator(n)
  for x in range(4):
    space(n)
  separator(n)
  for x in range(4):
    space(n)
  separator(n)

#Main
print_2byN(int(input("Enter an integer for 2byN: ")))
```